# Liouville theorem for fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there any Liouville type theorem for the half space problem
\begin{equation}
  \ \  \left\{\begin{aligned}
(-\Delta)^s v &= f(v)  &&\text{in } \mathbb R^N_+\\
 v  & =0 &&\text{in  }  \mathbb R^N \setminus \mathbb R^N_+\end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
where $s\in (0, 1)$ and $v$ changes sign. If $v$ is bounded and $f(v)=0$, does it imply $v \equiv 0.$

Comment: I find it confusing if someone changes their question in a way which invalidates a previously correct answer. Did you mean to ask a new question?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $v$ is necessarily zero.

The function $v$ in your question is $\alpha$-harmonic in the half-space $H = \mathbb{R}^N_+$. Lemma 17 in [K. Bogdan, *The boundary Harnack principle for the fractional Laplacian*. Studia Math. 123(1) (1997): 43–80] ([link](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm123/sm12313.pdf)) asserts that if $v$ is an $\alpha$-harmonic function in an open *bounded* set $D$, then $v$ is *regular $\alpha$-harmonic* in $D$, that is, it is given by a Poisson-type integral. Therefore, if $v$ is additionally zero outside $D$, then it is zero everywhere.

In our case, $H$ is not bounded. However, one can apply the same proof as in Bogdan's paper: boundedness of $D$ is required only to assert that the exit time from $D$ is finite with probability $1$, and the exit time from $H$ has this property.